# Embedded Developer, what skills are important

Tags: embedded, embedded-linux

I want to make a list of things that need to learn that is valuable for my career. What skills do you think are vital for an embedded developer, now and the distant future?

I have become quite proficient with C and ARM assembler through working with embedded Linux kernel and I'm about to dive into Linux drivers. However I can't help to think that I'm maybe narrowing my skill set to much. I want to keep working with embedded systems in the future but you never know the job market (paranoid that I'm going to be outsourced to China and India).

I feel that I'm currently quite weak with C++ and Java, I would also like to learn the Android kernel in the future. I also don't know any scripting languages.

Can anyone who has worked with embedded systems for a while, give some input on what skills/languages they think is vital for an embedded developer? Should I continue to only hone my C skills or should I learn new things.

Comment: Your question is too broad so it will get closed. Anyway, as a rule of thumb, the closer to the hardware you get, the more generic and broad knowledge you will get. If you know about the Linux kernel, or the Android kernel, you still work on the application level, and you will become a specialist at some particular applications. If you know generic, hardware-related C programming, some assembler of any kind, and electronics, then you have a core competence that can be used no matter the nature of the application.

Comment: Sorry, but this site is for technical problems which have specific answers, not career advice or questions soliciting an open ended list.

Comment: You don't know embedded until you work with registers directly :)

Comment: Brush up on your C++ and C#.  Even when working at the lowest levels, there are many times when you will want to create PC tools to help massage your data.  Also, C++ concepts won't hurt you in C land and will make your skills broader and more attractive if you do eventually get outsourced.  I was in your shoes 10 years ago and am glad I brushed up on C++ as a backup...

Comment: Sorry for breaking the rules but I have found several other questions like these on stackoverflow that have been very constructive on helping me see what is important from experienced developers, but not for embedded systems. Anyways, I'm happy with the answers that I Got!

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Here's my list:

- C essentials
- OOP/ C++ - classes, encapsulation, polymorphism, overloading/ overriding, templates
- Algorithms - search, sort, b-trees
- Design Patterns - factory, observer, singleton etc.
- Real Time Operating Systems - primitives (semaphore, mutex), scheduling techniques, user/ kernel space
- Linux fundamentals, driver writing, shell
- microprocessor fundamentals - interrupt processing, registers, assembly code, etc.
- microcontroller fundamentals - ADC, DAC, Timers, PWM, DMA, watchdog, etc.
- Memory - NOR, NAND, SRAM, DRAM, wear levelling
- Basic protocols - I2C, SPI, UART, LIN
- Advanced protocols - SATA, PCIE, USB, CAN, MOST
- Concurrent/ parallel programming - MPI for SMP etc.
- UML - class diagram, component diagram, state diagram, sequence diagram
- Perl or Python for scripting, for e.g. to modify simple text files.
- Java and Android
- Basic electronics - schematics reading, using oscilloscope, multimeter, soldering iron
- Specialized techniques for embedded programming e.g. debouncing of switches, resistive ladder switches, rotary encoders, etc.
- software engineering - SDLC, CMMI, agile methods e.g. SCRUM, version control (ClearCase, git, svn), bug tracking (JIRA?), static code checking, Lint, unit testing, continuous integration
- build environments - makefile, cmake
- Basic FPGA/ ASIC design, basic DSP

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for! Thank you, it seems I have alot to learn :)

Answer (score 7):

As mentioned by Lundin, this question is open to many different answers. You have from small battery-powered memory-constrained bare metal embedded devices to more complex systems running Linux.

First of all, it's very important to be a flexible developer. You need to be able to adapt to changes as quickly as possible. You may need to do a concept-proof prototype in just a couple of weeks in a language you've never used before, or to start working in a legacy project to fix a bug very quickly.

It's very important to know about software architecture concepts, RTOS, event-driven systems (embedded systems are reactive by nature) and modeling too (UML). Maybe test-driven development (TDD). These are language-agnostic, and will help you to develop good firmware from the ground-up.

Regarding to languages, I think that C is used in both small and big systems, so having a good background in C is a must. Here I'm not talking about c programming at a novice-level. I'm talking about knowing what the processor and the compiler do behind the scenes. According to what you mentioned, you probably have these skills. This is very helpful in the case of small systems, where every byte of RAM and ROM counts.
Knowing something about MISRA-C rules will help you to develop safer C code.

Probably you will need some scripting programming to perform automated testing, data processing, code-generating tools, etc. I use Python for all of this, and also some linux shell scripting.

Being able to design PC-based applications is useful for creating test fixtures to test the embedded devices in the production line, or maybe because the embedded device just needs a pc software to work, like a pocket USB-based oscilloscope. In this case, I use Qt, since it's cross-platform, but you can use Visual Studio with C# if you only want to work in Windows.

In the case of embedded systems, it's better if you have a solid hardware background. Also, you need to be able to use an oscilloscope, a logic analyzer, a signal generator, etc. Sometimes you will need to fix hardware problems with software. :)

Here is a small list of books I find very useful:

- Practical UML Statecharts in C/C++.
- UML Distilled.
- Making Embedded Systems.
- Computers as components.
- Embedded Software Primer.
- Better Embedded Systems Software.

I hope it helps.

Fernando

Comment: 1. Learn how to do code alignment - most embedded developers I saw in the last 20 years do not how to do it.

Answer (score 2):

Whatever the domain you want to select not only C programming you should know but you should also be good familiar with hardware.

It doesn't matter which domain your are working on (linux, vlsi, arm....). But matter how efficient  your code is running on the hardware.

If you really would like to work in embedded world, you will find your way.